# how to open the contents of SD cards in WP8.

Tags: lumia

i am not able to access the contents of my SD card in nokia lumia 520. i can only see that there is a SD card in my phone but i could not access the contents of card.

Comment: The SD card should be formatted by a phone before it can be read. Having a computer format it will not work.

Comment: If the app in the sd card is outdated version then it will not be shown.

Answer (score 1):

The images and videos are automatically shown in the Photo hub or in the Music hub.
The other files can be viewed using a file manager application like this

http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=1b38bafa-3fae-4644-9b2e-91b83f9c42b4

Answer (score 0):

Hope the last answer (@Matteo) is not what you're expecting. Hope you don't have an option to format too. Just format the card with other Lumia device and try again.